# Magento 2 Newsletter template path in cpanel

Tags: magento2.2, email-templates

I want to permanently change all the email templates from backend cPanel, 
but I'm enable to find the path :(

Does anyone knows where are the default email templates file located in cPanel magento 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Admin Panel, **Marketing > Communications > Email Templates.**

- Click on Add New Template, Choose the types of the Template: Header,
- Footer, or Message Templates. Click on Load Template, the
  corresponding format will appear.

For Your reference:[click to follow to www.mageplaza.com..](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-customize-email-template-transactional-email-magento-2.html)

Comment: This will help you only from Backend Admin side.